# How to get URL someone got redirected FROM

Tags: php

So,lets say Im the owner of awp.rs domain.

I made a simple redirect script so anyone who access domain awp.rs will be redirected to lets say: by.nies.host

Now, in by.nies.host I want to print awp.rs becouse Im redirected to that website by accesing awp.rs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php $url = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']); 
  echo $url['host'];
?>
```

you can add something like this to see what else the $url array contains. Something might be useful...

```
 <pre><?php print_r($url);?></pre>
```

Note that this referrer value is provided by the visitors browser and is not guaranteed to be accurate or to be immune to spoofing

Comment: Thanks, that was exacly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

> 'HTTP_REFERER'
>       The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents
>   will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as
>   a feature. **In short, it cannot really be trusted.**

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

---

alternative approach available as the owner of the redirecting and redirected to site:

in your script on: awp.rs

you could 'tag' the url you send the user to:

```
<?php
header("Location: http://by.nies.host?from=awp");
exit();
```

on by.nies.host you just check for the from in `$_GET`

```
echo "from $_GET['from']";
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to remove http:// and www. so it will display only the domain (awp.rs)? And, I dont understand, why it cannot be really trusted?

Comment: yes its a string like any other and can be manipulated - it cant be trusted as the users browser could set any value it wants to. i can tell my browser to say on every site that my REFERER is "mysite.com" for free advertising in logs; but in my personal case it is always blank, as i dont want you tracking me

Comment: see my answer @nogad.. I used the parse_url function so you can print just the hostname, or any/all of the other elements from a URL

Comment: @DuaneLortie that's not strictly what he asked in his comment above, as it leaves **www**

Comment: So, is there any way to "secure" that so it will work 100% ?

Comment: @Nikola no, none, http is a stateless protocol

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` but

> This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.

Answer (score 0):

If you redirect from your web site and want to refer to other website, the most easy way to do it is to set $_GET var. for example :

```
 by.nies?refer=YourSite
```

This is the easiest way